# String split in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a cell with value `WORD = '00000'`. But I just want to take the 4th and 5th value.
I already tried `KATA=WORD(4:5)`,

I also tried `KATA=WORD{4}`
But still cannot.

I got this error message :

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

How to split it? It's in `<cell>` type.

Comment: I Have seen that you never accepted any answer of all your questions. Are you aware of that feature? There is a green check mark next to each answer on the left. You should check an answer as accepted when it solved your problem, to let everybody know that you don't need further help.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to index the content of "first" (and only) cell element with curly brackets `{}` and then you can index the vector `()`. Therefore you need:

```
WORD = {'12345'}
output = WORD{1}(4:5)
```

which gives:

```
output =

45
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have something like this

```
>> word = {'00000'};
```

This is a 1x1 cell array containing a 1x5 char array. To index into the char array, you first need to index into the cell array, which you do with

```
>> word{1}
ans =
00000
```

And now you can index the 4th and 5th element

```
>> word{1}(4:5)
ans =
00
```